# I made a blog with Springboot3, but I can't add/delete/modify posts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, backend, blogs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v31QV.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41cHT.jpg)

I made a blog with Springboot3, but I can't add/delete/modify posts.

I made it using h2 server, but there is no problem with the membership registration, login, and logout functions. (I checked that the membership function works without any problem even when I enter the h2-console.)

However, after logging in, the registration, deletion, and modification functions of the post do not work normally (a message appears that it is complete, but it does not actually work)

I ask for your help. Developers of the world!!

I tried to search using googling and chat-gpt, but it didn't solve..

Please refer to the video (https://youtu.be/P09dX-zHG24)

Answer (score 0):

It might be some transaction problems but the information provided is not enough to solve your problem(if it's possible, provide the link to your code repository).
I recommend you to use the debugger and set the log level to DEBUG or TRACE. Set the breakpoints and send a request. Follow the logic step by step and see whether the data is properly stored.